# How to run only 1 annotated test method in TestNG ?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, testng

I have coded many Test Cases as Test Methods with @Test Annotation.

I have used only one class for all methods.

I want to run only 1 or 2 particular methods. And not run other methods. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by using an `.xml` file present at the root of the project.

In that `.xml` file you can you use `include`,

To include only a particular `@Test` method to run like the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>   
      <class name ="Full path to the Test class" />
         <methods>
            <include name="testMethodName" />
         </methods>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any framework right now? 
If not so it would be advisable to create a Keyword driven framework so that you can overcome above problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the required test method name under the methods tag as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="testNG.Event">
                <methods>
                    <include name="checkOut" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```